# JS settimeout doesn’t work in IE8…

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, timeout, click

```
<html>   
 <head>   
 <script>

var i;
i = 0;
function loop() { 
     i = i + 1;
     alert(String(i));
     setTimeout("loop()",1000);
}
setTimeout("loop()",1000);  
</script>   

 </head>   

 <body>   

</body>   
 </html>
```

Please try the above code in IE8 it will not give alert message for every 1 sec if you hold right click.

But in firefox it will give alert message even though if you dont release the right click.

I want the firefox functionality in IE8.

Comment: Do you mean that IE8 is not running your javascript while the right-click menu is *showing*? I don't think there's anything you can do about that...

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the holding down the button is a *blocking* event. That means that  all executions stops *while* it is being executed.

There is nothing you can do about this.

Are you using the right mouse button for something special, other than the default context menu?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout(timeOut,1000); 
// timer is set in milliseconds  = 1000 * sec

function timeOut() {
    alert('1 sec passed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction()
{
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
}
myFunction();
```

[more details](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)